# It does not do an insert if null value

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I am trying to insert each answer for each question in the database. Problem is that there is a possibility that a question may have no answers, so I tried the code below but it does not insert a db row if a question has no answer, what I was trying to do is that if no answer then display the string `No Answer` under the `Answer` column for that question:

```
 $answersql = "INSERT INTO Answer (QuestionId, Answer) 
    VALUES (?, ?)";
if (!$insertanswer = $mysqli->prepare($answersql)) {
    // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    echo __LINE__.': '.$mysqli->error;
}

if( $insert && $insertanswer)
{

    $c = count($_POST['numQuestion']);
    $question_ids = array();

    for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ )
    {

... //Question INSERT goes here

        $questionId = $mysqli->insert_id;

            $question_ids[$questionNo] = $questionId;

}

        $results = $_POST['value'];
        foreach($results as $id => $value) 
        {
            $answer = $value;

            $quesid = (int)$question_ids[$id];   

            foreach($value as $answer) 
            {

            if($answer == '' || $answer === null){
                $answer = 'No Answer';
            }

                $insertanswer->bind_param("is", $quesid, $answer);

                $insertanswer->execute();

                if ($insertanswer->errno) {
                    // Handle query error here
                    echo __LINE__.': '.$insertanswer->error;
                    break 7;
                }
            }
        }


    //close your statements at the end


    $insertanswer->close();

}
```

The `['value']` comes from an input:

```
var $newBtn = $(("<input class='answerBtnsRow answers' type='button' style='display:%s;' onclick='btnclick(this, " + gQuestionIndex + ");' />").replace('%s', $this.is(':visible') ? 'inline-block' : 'none')).attr('name', "value[" + gQuestionIndex + "][]").attr('value', $this.val()).attr('class', $this.attr('class')).attr('id', $this.attr('id') + 'Row');
```

UPDATE:

Below is the SHOW CREATE TABLE for the `Answer` Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Answer` (
 `AnswerId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `QuestionId` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `Answer` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`AnswerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=280 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Below is a var dump where if I set question 1 to have answers `B` and `C` and set question 2 to have no answers at all, it outputs the following:

```
var_dump($question_ids);
    var_dump($results);

 array(2) { 
[1]=> int(247) 
[2]=> int(248) 
} 
array(1) { 
[1]=> array(2) { 
[0]=> string(1) "B" 
[1]=> string(1) "C" } 
}
```

Comment: why dont you set a default value for empty feilds like (empty field = Z) ?

Comment: Should the values be allowed to be empty? If so, change the database to 'allow null' in those fields. If not, check for empty/null values before insert or update

Comment: @thaJeztah the field is set up to allow NULL

Comment: @NewBee The default method does not work if I set it

Comment: @thaJeztah But it does check for it before the insert as I have put it before the `execute()`. Oh thats what I think

Comment: Can you add the definition of the answer table in your database?

Comment: @thaJeztah can I ask what you mean when you said add the definition?

Comment: The SQL you use to create the Answer table e.g. "CREATE TABLE Answers (....)" as it seems you're using the same query over and over again, and if a single question has multiple answers, the previous one may be overwritten if not unique key is present.

Comment: @thaJeztah I have included the show create table for Answer Table in the update

Comment: Ok, it does have a primary key, from your original example, I thought questionId was the PK. Does the script produce errors at all?

Comment: do you see what is being posted to you php script? is there missing data there?

Comment: @thaJeztah It does not have any errors, I included some var_dumps to show what it is outputting

Comment: @jwoodward  I included a couple of var_dumps in update so you can see what it is outputting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell from your var_dumps that you have two questions, but only one set of answers. your design flaw doesn't link the answers to the questions, from what I can see.

no second index in $results, means no second set of answers, therefore no insert ...

but if you have three questions, and two answer sets, do those answers belong to question 1&2 or 2&3, or 1&3. I am not see how you mach your question id to the result set.

Comment: It is only not doing the insert if a question has no answers, if all questions has answers, then it doesn't miss any questions